# Running dashboard inside play-with-kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-play

I'm trying to start a dashboard inside [play-with-kubernetes](http://labs.play-with-k8s.com/)

Commands I'm running:

## start admin node

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address $(hostname -i)
```

## start network

```
kubectl apply -n kube-system -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

## allow master to hold nodes(?)

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

## Wait until dns is up

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

## join node (copy from admin startup, not from here)

```
kubeadm join --token 43d52c.d72308004d523ac4 10.0.21.3:6443
```

## download and run dashboard

```
curl -L -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml  | sed 's/targetPort: 8443/targetPort: 8443\n  type: NodePort/' | \
    kubectl apply -f -
```

Unfortunatelly dashboard is not available.
What should I do to correctly deploy it inside play-with-kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need heapster for dashboard to work. So execute these as well:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/raw/master/deploy/kube-config/rbac/heapster-rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/raw/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/heapster.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/influxdb.yaml
```

Also, unless you want to fiddle with authentication you need to grant dashboard admin privileges with something like this:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding insecure-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

Eventually a port link will appear (`30xxx`) but you will need to change the url scheme to https from http - and convince your browser that you don't care about the insecure certificate.

You should have a working dashboard now. Piece of cake ;)