# Kubernetes Play Dashboard Access from Outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-play

I wanted to learn Kubernetes using the Play with Kubernetes site but I seem to encounter some issue.
Here is what I did.
I created my kubernetes cluster by following the steps.

https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/p/bc3a57pk4ckg00bvdk70#bc3a57pk_bc3amn9k4ckg00bvdkv0

I had the following info with 1 master and 2 nodes

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.0.18:6443
Heapster is running at https://192.168.0.18:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.0.18:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy
monitoring-influxdb is running at https://192.168.0.18:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
```

I then deploy my Dashboard using the following steps.

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

[node1 ~]$ kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.98.185.58   <none>        443/TCP   58m
```

According to this issue https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/258
Dashboard port is no longer accessible in the UI

Now, how can I access my dashboard from the outside?
According to the FAQ here.. 
https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker

```
How can I connect to a published port from the outside world?
If you need to access your services from outside, use the following URL pattern http://ip<hyphen-ip>-<session_jd>-<port>.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com (i.e: http://ip-2-135-3-b8ir6vbg5vr00095iil0-8080.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com).
```

Given my IP address

```
https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/p/bc3a57pk4ckg00bvdk70#bc3a57pk_bc3amn9k4ckg00bvdkv0

I tried it with this but I am not successful in accessing the dashboard
http://ip-192-168-0-18-bc3a57pk4ckg00bvdk70-8443.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/
```

What did I do wrong or what I am missing?

Tried everything in this [Running dashboard inside play-with-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906977/running-dashboard-inside-play-with-kubernetes)
Nothing is successful

Any hints?

Comment: Hi, You just need to edit the `type=LoadBalancer` in order to expose the Dashboard to the public. I am assuming you are having k8s on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker/issues/259#issuecomment-387607163

You need to make some changes in the deployment in order to access from outside.

Comment: Error is executed when trying the curl command there... error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: did not find expected key